# How to return to original intent after user says Repeat during an elicit dialog on Alexa using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, lambda, sdk, alexa-skills-kit

```
class RepeatIntentHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """Handler for repeating the response to the user."""
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool
        return is_intent_name("AMAZON.RepeatIntent")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
        #logger.info("In RepeatHandler")
        attr = handler_input.attributes_manager.session_attributes
        response_builder = handler_input.response_builder
        #if "recent_response" in attr:
        cached_response_str = json.dumps(attr["recent_response"])
        cached_response = DefaultSerializer().deserialize(cached_response_str, Response)
        #return cached_response
        return cached_response
```

I have used this code for repeat intent.  when the user said to repeat it will repeat the question, but after repeating, when the user will give a response(give an answer to that repeated question), the flow will not return back to the pervious intent. and my skill was stopped.

I also tried UpdateIntent.

```
return cached_response.handler_input.response_builder.speak(speak_output).add_directive(delegate_directive.DelegateDirective(updated_intent=Intent(name="QuestionIntent"))).response
```

but it will show an error like

**AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'add_directive'**

so how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

**When you use ElicitDialog, if the user ask to repeat, then send back the directive for the elicitSlotDialogs in the repeatIntent.**

Maybe you don't need to use ElicitSlot

Remember that Alexa is like a deck of card, the user can pick any card at anytime. Maybe I will ask you to repeat the question and then I will ask your skill to stop or to do anything else.

Alexa understand a sentence and redirect it to your skill within a specific intent. Only from the user voice, it doesn't have any logic to go back on any intent.

So if it's an Intent with custom slots, it should trigger your intent, but if it's an Intent like `Amazon.YesIntent`, then you'll have to implement the logic to continue your flow from the session attributes.

Ex:

- User: Alexa, launch skill A. ---> LaunchRequest
- Alexa: Do you like coffee ?
- User: Repeat ---> RepeatIntent
- Alexa: Do you like coffee ?
- User: No ---> NoIntent (then in your logic, you have to define that it was the question for coffee)
- Alexa: Ok, and do you like Tea?
- User: No ---> NoIntent (Same behavior, you have to know within the NoIntent to save the user preference based on the question he was asked, and for that, use the session attributes to save the question asked: `session_attributes["question"] = "userLikeTea"`)

Comment: I have already tried with session.
attr["question_text"]=(ques["question_text"])

But this is not working and stops the skill. It will not accept the user's responses after a repeat.It will not go back to previous intent after user's response.

Comment: You need to ask the user to reply after your repeat intent then `.ask(speak_output)`

Comment: I have added but the error which i have faced is AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'handler_input'.

Comment: share the full code

Comment: Here is my full code link [https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1wpuxe57ak12oko/AABjGFrcLjX8Y9s_vxgBPEfxa/lambda?dl=0&preview=lambda_function.py&subfolder_nav_tracking=1]

Comment: provide your JSON interaction model as well so I can replicate

Comment: Here is my JSON file called repeat.json [https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1wpuxe57ak12oko/AABjGFrcLjX8Y9s_vxgBPEfxa/lambda?dl=0&preview=repeat.json&subfolder_nav_tracking=1%5D]

Comment: ok, what do you say to alexa after opening the skill. Do you have any survey id? From what part? Give me the flow where the repeat stops

Comment: Here is the screenshot named error.png,ss1.png and ss2.png : [https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1wpuxe57ak12oko/AABjGFrcLjX8Y9s_vxgBPEfxa/lambda?dl=0&subfolder_nav_tracking=1%5D%5D]

Comment: You have to be very clear when you ask question. And if you need debug help, even more. That is not clear enough. You code contains an API call to your company, therefore I cannot reproduce. If you need help, give us a code that is reproducible and remove all the useless steps. A simple skill, with an elicit slot & repeat intent. Including all the utterances you used to reproduce your issue. Don't expect StackOverflow to debug messy code & do your work. We're here to help, save us time and we will save yours.

Comment: Here is my whole downloaded skill without any changes the link is here : [https://www.dropbox.com/sh/kvh7gzfm56v65ag/AAA3wJJSXVjFQ40TN1uT1ud3a?dl=0]
`Steps to reproduce : 
U: Run final survey
A: If you need assistance, say “Help” anytime. Let's begin OpenEyes survey, okay?
U: Okay
A: Please tell me your survey ID
U: 334383
A: Question 1
U: Answer 
A: Question 2
U: Repeat
A: Gives error (And skill stops)`

Comment: Not working, create another skill, very simple, without API call, just with the repeat intent and share it if it's not working still